# using ssh keys in bash script

Tags: bash, ssh, key, tunnel

I've setup ssh keys form server A to server B and I can login to server B without a password. I'm trying to setup a reverse ssh tunnel in a bash script. From the command line if I do

```
ssh -N -R 1234:localhost:22 user@mydomain.co.uk -p 22
```

form server A it works as expected i.e no password required, however if I use it in a script

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/ssh -N -R 1234:localhost:22 user@mydomain.co.uk -p 22
```

I get asked for the password

```
user@mydomain.co.uk's password:
```

How do I make it so it uses the keys?

Comment: I believe you need to start your `ssh-agent` and add your key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to let `ssh` know where it should search for the keys, if they are not in standard location and not passphrase protected. The easiest thing is by specifying `-i` switch directly to `ssh`:

```
/usr/bin/ssh -i /path/to/key -N -R 1234:localhost:22 user@mydomain.co.uk -p 22
```

Or cleaner way in your `~/.ssh/config` like this:

```
Host mydomain.co.uk
  IdentityFile /path/to/key
```

But make sure the script is run with your user context, so the script will see the configuration file.

If you have keys in standard location (`~/.ssh/id_rsa`), your code should work just fine. Although it should work if you have your keys stored in `ssh-agent`, which you can verify using `ssh-add -L` before starting the script. `ssh-agent` also solve the problem, if he keys are passphrase protected.

Comment: excellent thanks, used the -i switch and it now works as expected    #!/bin/bash
   /usr/bin/ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -N -R ssh -N -R 1234:localhost:22 user@mydomain.co.uk -p 22

Comment: please, take a time to accept the answer if it worked for you and solved your problem.