# Where to store SSH keys

Tags: macos, ssh, rsa

I'm working through an eBook on python deployments. Their method for logging into Digital Ocean is to of course use SSH with keys. However, they instruct you to point to your production key (prod_key) in a project folder, and point to that folder every time you log in via SSH. So a standard login is:

```
ssh -i ./prod_key deployer@{my.IP.address}
```

This is tedious because I need to get to that folder every time I login via SSH. I'm also trying to use scp to copy some files, and I can't get it to work with this method. How can I move the prod_key so I do not have to use '-i' every time and just log in from any location while in terminal on my Mac?

Comment: Is creating an alias in your `bash_profile` or `bashrc` an option? For example: `alias servername='ssh -i /absolute/path/to/prod_key deployer@{my.IP.address}'`

Comment: How about creating a script e.g. `goto.sh <server_ip_address>` and include prod key path within script. `server_ip_address` can be taken in as argument

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using ssh keys in bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33848254/using-ssh-keys-in-bash-script)

Comment: Creating the alias worked. Thanks.